# VBA: How to create a function which counts cells based on fill color and specific text?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a function to count the number of cells which match desired text and fill color of the cells. here is my code so far:

```
Function TEXTANDCOLOR(Color As Range, text As String, rng As Range) As Long  

Dim NoCells As Long  
Dim CellColor As Long  
Dim Celltext As Long  
Dim rngCell As Range  

CellColor = Color.Interior.Color  
For Each rngCell In rng  
If rngCell.Interior.Color = CellColor Then  
    If rngCell.text = Celltext Then  
       NoCells = NoCells + 1  
       End If  
  End If  
Next rngCell  
TEXTANDCOLOR = NoCells  
End Function
```

the Output is 0 each time

Comment: `Celltext` has not been assigned a value yet. Also you probably should use `.Value` or `.Value2` instead of `.Text`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting for this?

Comment: Just an FYI if your cells in which your are checking are colored with conditional formatting this udf will not work.

Comment: Need to count cells based on color and text, data is being manually entered to a sheet from several sources, no conditional formatting used

Answer (score 0):

```
   If rngCell.text = Celltext Then
```

why do you compare the cell text against variable Celltext (declared long **integer**, and not **initialised**). Change it to:

```
   If rngCell.text = text Then
```

and it works.
[image: Test use]

Comment: this fix does not work" #NAME? error

Comment: #NAME? error occurs when you use a VBA function and the function had an error, but if we ignore the error. Have you compiled it to see there were no errors?

Try calling the function directly from the Immediate window:
Ctrl-G (opens the Immediate window), type the following (changing the parameters to point to your set-up):
? TEXTANDCOLOR(Color:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets!Sheet1.range("I4"), text:="z", rng:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets!Sheet1.range("B5:F10"))

and Enter. Does it run ok?